# Upgrading Macbook Pro memory

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade

I've seen on the Apple support site, that my Macbook Pro (late 2008) will support up to 4GB at 1066Mhz is this the actual maximums or will I be able to install say 8GB 1333Mhz memory?

Also I have different memory that appear identical:

http://www.dabs.com/products/kta-2gb-ddr3-1066-module-65L8.html?refs=4294946774
http://www.dabs.com/products/2gb-ddr3-1066-module-6DLP.html?refs=4294946774

Is either of these RAM suitable? the specs seem to match the listing on the Apple support site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different "late 2008" MacBook Pros. There's the 17" which was the last of the old "AlBook" designs, and the 15" that was the first unibody MBP. The former will take up to 8GB, but can only address 6GB; the latter will take 8GB after downloading and applying the most recent EFI firmware update.

Comment: I have the 15" model, so I will be able to install 8GB, how do I install an EFI firmware update? And will I be limited to 1066Mhz?

Comment: Go here for the EFI update: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL975

Comment: And you will be limited to 1066MHz, yes.